# Does VS.NET Pro get these DLLs for web api?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2013

When creating an asp.net api app in vs.net premium, it adds a lot of DLLS such as:

Antlr3.Runtime
EntityFramework
Microsoft.Owin (lots of these)

If I take my project and give it to someone that only has vs.net Pro, they are missing all the above DLLs.

Does vs.net Pro not know how to pull in the above references or is something else needed?

Is this even related to vs.net Premium?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the version of Visual Studio. These are nuget packages that contain 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Then why doesn't the other person's vs.net pull these down? The references all show as missing.

Comment: The other person must restore the nuget packages (with this [extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4ec1526c-4a8c-4a84-b702-b21a8f5293ca) I can't remember if it came preinstalled in VS2013 or not) or using the standalone nuget.exe tool.

Comment: Unsure if this is relevant in 2013 - in order for the tooling to "know" (what packages to install/restore), the project should have a `packages.config` file (xml). Hth.

Comment: packages.config is there but doesn't help others.

Comment: After adding the above extension, it fixed the majority of issues. But some references still don't come through. Owin is one. Although in nuget, it has a green check mark (as do the others that are still missing). Any idea how to fix these others?